# Can i Push UINavigationController From another UIViewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I think its a stupid question but i tried to find a solution for my case but i fail...

I have application started with login screen after login i present MainUIViewController, from main i have many buttons one of them to open a new UINavigationController.. is that possible?

```
[window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
```

If i set navigation as main view its work,, but not from another UIViewController..

also i have tried

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        [self.view addSubview:[self.navController view]];// = [self.navController view];
    }
     return self;
}
```

but fail

thanks for suggestions

Comment: Personally i'd set the MainView to show a NavigationController then when loading the first view checking if the user is logged in, if they aren't present the login screen at a modal without an animation so it's the first view the user sees. Then when the user has logged in you can then dismiss the login modal. May be a better approach?

Comment: Thank, I thought in your suggestion when i fail.
but i still try to find a solution for my problem if that applicable on IOS.

Comment: is the idea just to hide/show the navigation bar?

Comment: hhhhh, i really don't remember the question but after 5 year+, just got many downvote for the question... how are some people are really ST...D

Answer (score 1):

Is the MainUIViewController the root view controller of the window? If so, why don't you add it to a UINavigationController and then make the nav controller the root view controller of the window? If you're concerned with the MainUIViewController not needing a navigation bar, you can very easily hide this with the setNavigationBarHidden: method on UINavigationController. You can then unhide it on the subsequent view controllers. This way, you start off with the navigation controller and simply push new view controllers onto the stack.